# NSAttributedString draw location different on 10.13 and 10.14+

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I use `NSAttributedString`s `draw(in: rect)` to draw a string into a view (same problem occurs with a plain `NSString`). Now the outcome seems to be different to what deployment target I set in Xcode. If the deployment target is `10.13`, the draw call renders it like this

[image]

where the red box represents `rect`. If I switch the deployment target to `10.14` or above without touching the code, the same draw call renders like this

[image]

Create an empty project, set the `NSWindow`s content view class to `TestView` and create the class below.

```
class TestView: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        NSAttributedString(string: "9", attributes: [
            .font: NSFont.userFixedPitchFont(ofSize: 48)!,
            .foregroundColor: NSColor.labelColor
        ]).draw(in: bounds)
    }
}
```

Now switch between 10.13 and 10.14+ deployment target and the string location will shift. If you would check the strings `.size()` it returns `68` on 10.13 and `58` on 10.14+.

How do I make this consistent between platforms? Since it is inside a package the DT could vary, and I want to avoid different code paths.

Moreover the 10.14+ version seems more "correct".

Comment: I encountered the same problem, how did it work out in the end?

Comment: Went with some suboptimal hardcoded solution, but it won't matter for much longer since I will simply raise my deployment target to 10.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried changing the font and noticed that the issue disappears if you're using the default system font. This led me to believe that the problem lies with the fixed-pitch font — it appears to have a different line-height depending on the DT.

Setting a specific line-height via a paragraph style fixes it:

```swift
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 58
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 58
    NSAttributedString(string: "9", attributes: [
        .font: NSFont.userFixedPitchFont(ofSize: 48)!,
        .foregroundColor: NSColor.labelColor,
        .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
    ]).draw(in: bounds)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reply I got from Apple:

This is intended behavior. Apps deploying to macOS 10.14 or later will get the newer typesetter behavior, which affects the spacing of glyphs and the line height of text. The text field height is affected by the line height of the text measurement.

The typesetter behavior change corrected a long-standing floating point rounding error that resulted in extra height being added to the default ascender, so the text may measure smaller than previously.

Please refer to macOS 10.14 AppKit release notes documenting this change: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/appkit-release-notes-for-macos-10_14